# Реализация Winsock как способ авторизации

Tags: c++, база-данных, авторизация, winsock

Решил спросить по поводу работы с winsock.
Не до конца понимаю, что это из себя представляет, но хотел бы поинтересоваться возможностями данной библиотеки.

У меня уже есть написанные консольные программы.
Я хотел бы сделать способ авторизации на следующих пунктах.

1. Пользователю предоставляется уникальный идентификатор.
   С помощью этот id, у него должен происходить вход в софт.
2. Когда генерируется этот id, он с клиента должен отправляться на сервер.
3. Сервер обрабатывает id и если он существует в конкретной базе данных — то разрешает вход в программу.
4. Сервер должен принимать id  и сверять его с базой данных.

Так вот, в чем вопрос то. Смогу ли я реализовать подобные функции используя WinSock?
​​​​​​​Т.е. может ли сервер работать с базами данных?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinSock - это библиотека работы с сокетами.

Сокет - это, простыми словами говоря, "шланг", куда можно с обеих сторон засовывать байты, и они будут "вылезать" на другой стороне.

Есть множество примеров работы с WinSock, и практически все они - реализуют архитектуру "клиент - сервер"

Приментительно к Вашей задаче:

Вы хотите, чтобы клиент открывал соединение с сервером и посылал запрос на сервер. Сервер обрабатывал запрос и отвечал клиенту в духе "пароль правильный или пароль неправильный"

С помощью WinSock это, без сомнения, можно сделать.

Вам придется придумать протокол передачи, потому что WinSock не накладывает никаких ограничений на передаваемую информацию, а на сервере - сделать обработку приходящих запросов.

Скоре всего, протокол будет очень простым: "на сервере ловим строку, оканчивающуюся нулевым байтом. строка закодирована в ASCII. в строке содержится уникальный идентификатор. Отвтетить надо строкой, содержащей yes или no и оканчивающейся нулевым байтом"

Как то так.